# No log found, also no error reported

Tags: logging, google-apps-script

I am using the below app script and try looking for a specific file under a specific folder in my g drive. However, it seems there is no either error or logging even I add a logger to the button.

```
function getGdrive(Folder) {

  var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(('foldername'));
  var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName('filename /.*text.*/'); 
  while (files.hasNext()){
    var file = files.next();
    Logger.log(file.getName());
  }

}
```

Basically, the filename only has 2 characters, and '/.*text.*/' is only for wildcast purpose.

Look forward to hearing yours. Thx!

Comment: To extend my question above, all related files are only duty schedule in spreadsheet format and I would like to have time to be add on my google calendar with some automation order...

Comment: try adding your code in between try and catch. In Catch print the error

Comment: Try using do while and nextpagetoken to get more pages of output.

Comment: @Cooper only relevant in advanced service - `DriveApp` does that but for you. @ op store your search in a variable, e.g. `var filenameSearch = 'filename /.*text.*/';` and then before calling `while`, add this line `if (!files.hasNext()) throw new Error("No results for filename search '" + filenameSearch + "'");` you'll at least get a very visible notification of 0 results. Also note that you don't use your function input parameter `Folder`...

Comment: Consider reviewing documentation as well.. quite sure that regex is not valid as an input to `get by name` maybe try https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#searchfilesparams

Comment: Fully agree with @tehhowch, use "search" when you want to search

Comment: @tehhowch Thanks...I didn't realize that.

Comment: Thx all for the prompt reply!